# Filtering by .docx in ios document picker

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin

What is the *Uniform Type Identifer* to provide to a `UIDocumentMenuViewController` to allow a user to select *.docx files?

The documentation in [System-Declared Uniform Type Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1) does not list a public UTType that allows filtering by .docx. An identifier exists for a standard *.doc file but not *.docx, is there instead an alternate UTType?

This is my current code:

```
var allowedDocumentTypes = new string[] {
    UTType.RTF,
    UTType.Text,
    UTType.PDF,
    UTType.UTF8PlainText,
    UTType.RTFD,
    UTType.UTF16ExternalPlainText,
    UTType.UTF16PlainText,
    UTType.UTF8PlainText,
    UTType.FlatRTFD,
    "com.microsoft.word.doc",
    "com.microsoft.word.docx" // An attempt to include docx filtering.
};

var pickerMenu = new UIDocumentMenuViewController(allowedDocumentTypes, UIDocumentPickerMode.Open);
pickerMenu.DidPickDocumentPicker += (sender, args) =>
{
    args.DocumentPicker.DidPickDocument += (sndr, pArgs) =>
    {
        var securityEnabled = pArgs.Url.StartAccessingSecurityScopedResource();

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(pArgs.Url.Path);

        var result = new SelectFileResult();
        result.FilePath = fi.FullName;
        result.FileName = fi.Name;

        NSUrlRequest urlReq = NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(pArgs.Url);
        NSUrlResponse response;
        NSError error;;
        var data = NSUrlConnection.SendSynchronousRequest(urlReq, out response, out error);

        result.MimeType = response.MimeType;

        Action onFileConsumeDone = () =>
        {
            pArgs.Url.StopAccessingSecurityScopedResource();
        };

        onFileSelected(result, onFileConsumeDone);

    };

    // Display the document picker
    AppDelegate.TopViewController.PresentViewController(args.DocumentPicker, true, null);
};

pickerMenu.ModalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover;
AppDelegate.TopViewController.PresentViewController(pickerMenu, true, null);
```

I had a shot in the dark and included the identifier `com.microsoft.word.docx` but it does not trigger filtering by docx.

My current solution is C# but objective-c and swift solutions accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try `org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: That was it Jason!

Comment: Apple trying hard to keep the words docx and Microsoft out of their system :D

Answer (score 3):

Try
let supportedTypes: [UTType] = [UTType.content]